# C# Split gives an error

Tags: c#, split

I have an array of Strings

```
 String[] theStringArray ={"A,B,C,D,E,F,G",
               "H,I,J,K,L,M,N"};
```

I have an empty string array I am trying to set its contents to the contents of the 0 index of the above array.

```
String[] theNewArray;

theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(",");
```

This gives an error.What I have Done wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple quotes

```
String[] theNewArray;

theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(',');
```

Comment: Wow such a simple oversight.Thanks

Comment: Take it easy tjameson. It only let's me mark it as correct 15 minutes after I ask the question.It is marked correct :)

Answer (score 1):

`String` is not implicitly convertible to `char[]`, which is what `Split` expects.

```
theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(',');
```

If you need to split by more than one character, you can use

```
theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(",.;:".ToCharArray());
```

In the future, it is helpful to tell what error message you're getting. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Split()` method takes a char, not a string.  Change your code to this (note the single quotes):

```
theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is:

> The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

This is because you're passing the Split method a string (double-quotes) rather than a character (single-quotes).

Try this instead:

```
theNewArray =  theStringArray[0].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

hey man use theString.split(",");

like this

```
http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use single quotes to specify you mean a char[] and not a string, even if the string is one char long.

It is also worth noting that Join requires double quotes. Quite unintuitive don't you think?!

```
var joinString = string.Join("|", join);
var string[] split = joinString.Split('|');
```